# Web site keeps on refreshing due to cookie expiration and authentication issue

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller

Below is the configuration and sign in code  I have used .But if I have not signed out from the application , after some hours if I try to sign in It will keep on refreshing

Startup.cs has below code

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {       app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = ClientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },
  
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    },
                    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
                }
            );
}
```

signin page

```
public void SignIn()
    {
         if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties 
            { RedirectUri = "/", IsPersistent = true },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
     }
```

Comment: Able to fix this issue by calling cookiemanger in below code  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
                SlidingExpiration = true, CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
            });

Answer (score 1):

To start: `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is obsolete. Configure OpenIdConnect authentication with AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect in ConfigureServices. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470 for more details.

So at least I'd strongly advice to upgrade to the latest supported standards.

Besides the fact that there is too little information to determine what might be wrong, it might be a good idea to check out the example regarding OIDC: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC